# If a number $7^n$ has 40 digits, show that this number contains a digit which repeats at least 5 times.

Tags: combinatorics

I tried solving this problem using the contradiction method: if I can't write a number with 40 digits using each of the digits from 0 to 9 less than 5 times => one of the digits must repeat at least 5 times. The problem is that you can, 4 times the 10 available digits = 40 digits. 
 
Then I thought that one of the digits from 0 to 9 probably does not appear in a number of the form $7^n$ but all of them do appear as seen in the sequence $$7,49,343,2401,16807,117649,823543$$
I don't think the rule of divisibility with 7 or the ending digits of a power of 7 will help me either so I want some ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If there is no digit appearing at least $5$ times , every digit appears exactly $4$ times , but such a number must be divisible by $9$ , not possible for a power of $7$. That's it.

Comment: @Peter It was clever!

Comment: These days you can just ask Alpha to compute the power.  There will be no more than two of them with $40$ digits.  You can just show which digit is there at least $5$ times.

Comment: @RossMillikan I actually did that before posting the question but that feels like cheating.

Comment: @Peter,Clever,You should post it as answer